# Which Apple ID is used for Apple Music—iCloud or iTunes?

Tags: apple-id, apple-music

I have different Apple IDs for iCloud (backups, iCloud Drive, Keychain Sync...) and iTunes (purchasing media—music and movies.) They are in different countries.

Which Apple ID is used if I sign up for Apple Music?

Is it even possible to be logged in with different iCloud and iTunes IDs and use Apple Music?

Comment: Note that none of the answers to this question (https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/197457/can-i-use-one-apple-id-for-apple-music-and-another-for-itunes-app-store) help me, please don't mark this as a dup.

Answer (score 2):

Your iTunes Apple ID is used. I also use two Apple IDs and the one logged in to iTunes & App Store in Settings is the one which was used.

Comment: I think this might actually be OK for my use case: I have all my purchases under Apple ID X (US), and iCloud (etc) under Apple ID Y (AU). If I change the country of Y to DE and subscribe to an Apple Music family plan, it will "match" all the music on my phone (including purchases from ID X) and make them available in my Apple Music account on ID Y. I just have to log in for iTunes with ID Y usually, but be careful to only purchase Apps, iBooks and movies when logged in as ID X. Does this sound like it'll work?